# C# - client streaming in multithreaded server

Tags: c#, multithreading, client-server, networkstream

I have achieved sending message client -> server and actually connecting many clients simultaneously. But what I want to do is i.e. connect 2 clients and make them chat between themselves. And if 3rd client connects - then so he starts chatting with both other clients.

By now I am on the stage of chatting client->server->client separately from another c->s->c. What happens is - I run client1 and everything is OK. Then I run client2 and with it everything is OK, but the 1st client stops working and then the first message I acquire on the 2nd client is the last message that I sent from client1 (but that didn't actually receive back to it from server).
 So I suppose there's problem with the streams - that the 2 clients somehow acquire each-other's streams.
 Here is the some parts of the server (relevant ones): [TheServer](http://pastebin.com/3hJV4ydY)

*HandleClientComm(object client)* is handling the receive-send operations.

And here is the client side code part, that handles the receive-send operations:[TheClient](http://pastebin.com/h5KpnkXB)

And I get 
`An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred...` in
 in the Server at 
`Byte[] bData = new Byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(bSize, 0)];`

sooo... yeah, there's something wrong with the streams (on my opinion). But I don't really know how make the server distinguish between the clients' threads correctly.

I am open for any suggestions.

P.S. I am not posting the code directly here because it will get too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first part of `HandleClientComm()`:

```
private void HandleClientComm(object client)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
    NetworkStream stm = clientList[n].GetStream();
    msg = new TheMessage();
```

You have the `tcpClient`, which is the client you sent as a parameter, but the `NetworkStream` is not for *that* client, but for `clientList[n]`, and `n` is a class-wide variable. Later in that method, within the `while` loop, you use:

```
    stm = clientList[n].GetStream();
```

As soon as you increase `n`, all threads running `HandleClientComm()` will receive and send messages from/to the last client.

The `NetworkStream` you use in `HandleClientComm()` should be created from the `tpcClient` instead, so each thread running `HandleClientComm()` serves its own client:

```
    stm = theClient.GetStream();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! :) 
What is left now is to make it chat between clients and if I have 4 clients, then make each client find another endpoint and not mix between more than 2 clients. But that I will figure out (I hope...). :)